# javascript: not having to use all the IDs in a html file?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to use the same .js for a bunch of html pages, but not necessarily all the ID's from this .js in every single page. Right now, if I don't use one ID; no ID's are showing at all.

```
var yes = 'Yes';
var no = 'No';
var available = 'Available:&nbsp;';

document.getElementById("001").innerHTML=available+yes;
document.getElementById("002").innerHTML=available+no;
document.getElementById("003").innerHTML=available+yes;
```

A html with this works fine:

```
 <div id="001"></div>
 <div id="002"></div>
 <div id="003"></div>
```

A html with this, not so fine:

```
 <div id="002"></div>
 <div id="003"></div>
```

What to do to make it run even though some ID's arn't being used?

Complete noob to this, there's probably a super simple solution to it(?) - but I can't find it. Hopefully, someone here can help me - without totally bashing me, or telling me how much of a bad praxis this is and that I should rewrite it in some mega haxxor language that I havn't even heard of :D

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `document.getElementById()` function returns `null` if no matching element is found. `null.innerHTML` is an error that stops the current script executing. So you just have to test for `null`:

```
var el = document.getElementById("001");
if (el != null) el.innerHTML = available + yes;
```

The `null` test can be simplified to:

```
if (el) el.innerHTML = available + yes;
```

If element "001" is *always* going to be "yes", "002" is always going to be "no" and so forth then you can do this:

```
var results = {"001" : yes, "002" : no, "003" : yes};
var el, k;
for (k in results) {
    el = document.getElementById(k);
    if (el) el.innerHTML = available + results[k];
}
```

Comment: This seems to do the trick and require the least amount of "recoding". I'm curios about one thing tho; how come I can use the same variable to define all these different ID's (the "el" in your example)? Is that something that goes for js overall maybe... It's just a little counter intuative to me. P.S. Thank you so much for such a pedagocial response too.

Comment: _'the "el" in your example'_ - Variables can be reassigned values at any time, so you can use a single `el` variable to process all of your html elements. But I suspect you meant to ask about the `results` variable, which is an object created from an object literal. For more information about that, read the MDN article [Working With Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) (see the "creating new objects" section for object literal syntax as used in my answer).

Comment: No no, I went with your first solution :) And I ment to ask about the "el". Worked perfectly! Just seems odd to me that I have different values to one variable:

var el = document.getElementById("001");
var el = document.getElementById("002");
var el = document.getElementById("003");

etc. But then again, I'm the noob :D

Comment: Oh right. Well then you'd only declare `el` with `var` once, then you'd keep using it with `el = ...`.

Answer (score 1):

While I'd question why you'd need incrementing numeric IDs like that, one solution would simply be to keep an map of IDs to values, then iterate the map checking for `null`.

```
var m = {
    "001":yes,
    "002":no,
    "003":yes
};

for (var p in m) {
    var el = document.getElementById(p);
    if (el)  // or if (el !== null)
        el.innerHTML = available + m[p];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap it with if(document.getElementById("id")!==null) ?

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the whole thing in a `try` statement to avoid any issues and put code afterwards into a `finally` statement::

```
try{
document.getElementById("001").innerHTML=available+yes;
document.getElementById("002").innerHTML=available+no;
document.getElementById("003").innerHTML=available+yes;
//etc
}
finally{
    //any other code that there is after the id stuff
}
```

that'll prevent errors, so if something fails, it will still continue

Comment: That'll also prevent the rest of the code in the block from running once you encounter an error.,

Comment: Hmmm... I really think you'd need to wrap each one in a separate `try/catch`. When you get to the `finally`, you still don't know where you left off. For example if "002" throws, how will you know that you need to continue with `"003"`.

Comment: ...and you forgot the `catch(e) {}` block. ;-)

Comment: @cookiemonster there doesn't NEED to be a catch block, it'll still be valid. And about seperate tries...whatever. This is a crude idea anyways

Comment: The `catch` is required. There's no such thing as a `try{}` alone in JS. :-)

Comment: @cookiemonster - According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) the `catch` is optional if you have a `finally`.

Comment: yep, as @nnnnnn said: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FStatements%2Ftry...catch it's optional

Comment: @nnnnnn: Yes, you're right. The original code only had `try{}` without `finally{}`.

Comment: Note though that if you have `finally` without `catch` the code in the `finally` will run and then the script will still crash because you haven't actually caught the error. (So any code after the end of the `finally` block won't be executed.)

Comment: @Markasoftware: But the separate `try`'s still stands. OP wants to invoke `getElementById` on all that exist. Yours will halt the attempt after the first error, so if `"002"` fails, the `"003"` will be lost.